# Trying to derive the Bianchi identities $R_{[abc]d}=0$ and $\nabla_{[a}R_{bc]}^{de}=0$

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

I am not sure if we are working under the vielbein formalism. Anyway, I am trying to show
$$R_{[abc]d}=0\text{ and }\nabla_{[a}R_{bc]}^{de}=0.$$
Is it helpful to plug
$$[\nabla_a,\nabla_b]=\frac{1}{2}R_{ab}^{cd}M_{dc}$$
into the Jacobi identity $[\nabla_a,[\nabla_b,\nabla_c]]+[\nabla_b,[\nabla_c,\nabla_a]]+[\nabla_c,[\nabla_a,\nabla_b]]=0$? For your information, $\nabla_a=e_a^\mu\partial_\mu+\frac{1}{2}\omega_a^{bc}M_{cb}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Bianchi identities follows from Jacobi

$$
\frac{1}{6!}[[\nabla_{[a},\nabla_{b}],\nabla_{c]}]=\frac{1}{3}\Big([[\nabla_{a},\nabla_{b}],\nabla_{c}]+[[\nabla_{b},\nabla_{c}],\nabla_{a}]+[[\nabla_{c},\nabla_{a}],\nabla_{b}]\Big)=0
$$

and in your case you are probably assuming zero torsion

$$
T_{abc}=(\nabla_{[a}e_{b]}\,^{m})e_{mc}=(e_{[a}\,^{m}\partial_{m}e_{b]}\,^{n})e_{nc}+\omega_{[ab]c}=0\,.
$$

Since $\omega_{a(bc)}=0$ we have

$$
\omega_{abc}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{[ab]c}-\omega_{[bc]a}+\omega_{[ca]b}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{a(bc)}+\omega_{b(ca)}-\omega_{c(ba)}\right)=
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega_{[ab]c}-\omega_{[bc]a}+\omega_{[ca]b}\right)
$$
so $\omega_{abc}$ is fixed in terms of $e_{a}\,^{m}$ if $T_{abc}=0$.